# windows registry setting for timeoffset from gmt is not getting updated

Tags: windows-server-2008, timezone-offset, registrykey

windows server has a registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation where the field ActiveTimeBias will return the offset in minutes from GMT for the machine that you are running on.

we have a web application that needs to present a user with their local time on an html page that we generate.  we do this by having them set a preference for their timezone and then fetch the above value so that can compare server time and client time and do the correct calculation.

on servers that we have built this works great.  we are deploying our application into a tier 1 cloud provider who is providing a windows server ami that we configure and use.  what we have found is that when you use the clock control panel on a local server, the registry entrys for TimeZoneInformation are correct.  when we do the same for this virtual machine, the entrys are correct with the exception of ActiveTimeBias.

Microsoft cautions against diddling the individual value in their usual fashion.

question for the community - has anyone else encountered this problem and if so, how  did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

One usually doesn't program directly against these registry keys.  For example, in .Net, we have the `TimeZoneInfo` class.  It uses the same data, but in a much more developer-friendly way.

Regarding your particular question, the `ActiveTimeBias` key hold the current offset from UTC for the time zone that your server is set to.  If your server is in a time zone that follows daylight savings rules, then this will change twice a year.  If you manually update your time zone and refresh the registry, you will see it change.

The best advice I can offer is that since the timezone of the server is likely to be unimportant to anyone, you should set it to UTC.

See also: [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices)